# Add HTML elements into Angular Component

Tags: html, angular, components

How to add a angular html element into a component in run time.

Let the html element is a H1 tag having angular expression.

```html
<h1>{{testHeading}}</h1>
```

I want to insert this tag into a component. With persisting it's dynamic angular property.
Here "testHeading" is a angular variable.

Am trying to add the element using the following method:

```
addComponent(component:any){
    let componentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver
    .resolveComponentFactory(component)
    .create(this.injector);

    this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);

    const domElem = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>)
    .rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

    var newcontent = document.createElement('div');
    newcontent.innerHTML = `<h1>${this.demoText}</h1>`;
    domElem.appendChild(newcontent);

    document.getElementById("testid").appendChild(domElem);
}
```

Comment: You should go with dynamic component loader ref: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a container in your template

```html
<div #container></div>
```

Create a container reference by

```js
@ViewChild('container') container: ElementRef;
```

And after view init you can access the container element for example by

```js
container.nativeElement.innerHTML = `<h1>${yourString}</h1`;
```

**Edit 2023:** Updated ViewChild syntax

Comment: Great solution my dear bro, It's working fine.
But I've one doubt what is the `${yourString}`. I have never use a expression like this, I always use {{yourString}}.
Could you please explain this or share a ref link where I'll get know about `${yourString}` method.

Comment: You're welcome :) since it seems you are new to SO: If solutions are working for you, you should except the related answers as well.

Comment: `{{yourString}}` is interpolation in `.html`.
`${yourString}` is interpolation in `.ts`.

Comment: @HarunurRashid this actually is the `.ts` file.

Comment: @ngfelixl, One more thing in the expression ${yourString}` if I need to declare the  variable 'yourString' in the child component where I need insert the HTML element (<h1>).Then it will showing error that 'yourString' is not defined, in the parent component.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Would you like to update your question with the complete component class (.ts)?

Comment: @ngfelixl, I've updated the question. Could you please look into it?

Comment: And your exact problem is that `this.demoText` is not defined?

Comment: Yes, I need to define the variable(this.demoText) in the child component, into which am inserting the element(<h1>).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182414/discussion-between-ngfelixl-and-sanjaya).